# Ansible with_dict expects a dict - blank Null dictionary variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible 1.9.4

In my `group_vars/slave/slave` file, I have the following variable set to NULL value (none/not defined/empty string to be more accurate):

```
# NFS mount settings
slave_nfsmount:
```

Playbook calls a task/action:

```
  - name: Ensure nfs mount directory exists
    file: path={{item.key}} state=directory
    with_dict: "{{slave_nfsmount | default({})}}"
    ignore_errors: yes
```

Getting an error mesg:

```
TASK: [Ensure nfs mount directory exists] ************************************** 
fatal: [12.19.22.33] => with_dict expects a dict

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I **don't** want to set the value of slave_nfsmount variable in global_vars/slave/slave file (as a user can pass this value at command line or it can be made available some other way depending upon what a user wants to pass at runtime or not). Because, currently it's using a NULL, blank/none value for **slave_nfsmount** variable, I'm using `"{{ slave_nfsmount | default({})}}"` with the `with_dict:` statement.

How can I make this work **when the value is blank/null/not defined/empty** so that my playbook won't fail?

I tried giving: `and slave_nfsmount is not defined`

or
`ignore_errors: yes` (`True`), but it didn't work, the playbook still failed with a fatal error as shown above.

Comment: Agree @techraf, but the issue is still valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default()` filter returns the default value only if the var is **undefined**.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#default

> If the value is undefined it will return the passed default value, otherwise the value of the variable:

In your case, `slave_nfsmount` is defined and it's NULL.

If you want the var be overridden by extra vars (i.e. the `-e` argument), give it a default value at the time you initialize it:

```
slave_nfsmount: {}
```

Comment: that makes sense actually (relevant to my question). Still wondering, if this fixes the issue, great but why `ignore_errors: yes` or `ignore_errors: True` didn't IGNORE/SKIP the error..

Comment: Because it's like syntax/compilation error (unresolvable reference to variable), but not an error generated by the task itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following variable set to NULL value (none/not defined)

No, you have not. You have a defined variable.

Use for example a ternary filter.

```
with_dict: "{{slave_nfsmount | ternary(slave_nfsmount, {})}}"
```

Comment: No, the value is NULL.